# Ionic 3 can't use ion-* components inside my custom components

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have recently upgraded to Ionic 3 from Ionic 2, and I created **components.module.ts** file and declared and exported each custom component I have, and then imported this single file in every page module I have.

So now the problem is that I can't use ion-* components inside my own components, because I did not imported the `IonicModule.forRoot(..)` inside my components.module.

The error is:

> "Template parse errors: 'ion-spinner' is not a known element ..."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add your components module file?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Alright, so I figured out the solution:

All i needed was to import `IonicModule` in `components.module`, **without** `forRoot(..)`.

Also note that Angular's `CommonModule` is also necessary to make Angular's directives work, so you probably need to import it too.

Comment: Without the `foorRoot` part `ionic serve` throws an error: `Error: Could not find IonicModule.forRoot call in "imports"`.

Comment: @Codeicus do you have `IonicModule.forRoot` in your app module? (the main module)

Comment: @eliran-peer yes, I have the following code:

`@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ..._pages, ..._components, ..._pipes ],
  imports: [ ..._modules, ..._page_modules,
    IonicModule.forRoot(<AppComponentsClassExport>, <AppConfigJSON>)
  ],
<...>`

Comment: Took me several hours to stumble on this nice solution for the current angular version.

Answer (score 27):

Based on Eliran response, here you are an example in case somebody need something visual, in `components.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
  CommonModule, <<<< add the angular common module
  IonicModule <<<< add the ionic module
 ],
 ...
})
```