# "ion-button + icon-only" inside component not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3.*, tring to create a component that contains just a button.

The component code is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'profile-button',
  templateUrl: 'profile-button.html',
})
export class ProfileButtonComponent {
  constructor(
    private popoverCtrl: PopoverController
  ) {}

  /**
   * Present the Profile popover
   * @param ev
   * @returns {Promise<any>}
   */
  async presentPopover(ev) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(ProfilePopover);

    return popover.present({
      ev
    });
  }
}
```

and my template is:

```
<button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)" title="Profile">
    <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

**The problem:**

The problem is that the `icon-only` directive is just ignored. The button still have a background color.
If I put the template outside the component, it shows the right style.

Looks like the directives is not available inside a Component. My component is inside a custom module, not on AppModule.

How can I solve this? Found that on Ionic2 i need to import the directives manually, but it don't work on Ionic3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue, maybe with an workarround:

1. Changed the component selector to attribute selector: `[profile-button]`
2. Wrapped the template in a `<ion-buttons end>` tag
3. Called the component as an attribute of `<ion-buttons end>`

`<ion-buttons profile-button end></ion-buttons>`

**Note:** The issue wasn't with `icon-only` directive. But it's a style issue on Ionic that required the button directly child of the toolbar or ion-buttons to get proper styles.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution on [another S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425090/ionic-3-cant-use-ion-components-inside-my-custom-components/43425661).

In your *.module.ts add  `IonicModule` into `imports` section.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,  // <-- standard Angular module
    IonicModule    // <-- standard ionic module
  ], ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template try adding your content inside a ion-content

```
<ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: But it is not ion-content. It's used on header, wrap it inside a ion-content will break style.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `ion-button` and add:

```
class="disable-hover button button-ios button-clear button-clear-ios button-clear-ios-dark"
```

change `dark` as you want.